# Given that $\pi=2\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ use the properties of the integral to compute $\int_{-2}^{2}(x-3)\sqrt{4-x^2}dx$ in terms of $\pi$.

Tags: calculus

This is part *c* of the exercise set 2.4 in Apostol's Calculus 2nd Ed. We are only supposed to use the properties of the integral such as: linearity, additivity with respect to the interval of integration, invariance under translation, expansion or contraction of the interval of integration, or any consequences of them. A hint would be helpful.

Comment: it must be $-6\pi$

Comment: What property did you use?

Comment: Do you have substitution?

Comment: No, I thought about that too. All though it is ok to substitute variables into the bounds of integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
\int_{x=-2}^{2} (x-3)\sqrt{4-x^{2}} = 2\int_{x=-1}^{1}(2x-3)2\sqrt{1-x^{2}} = 8\int_{x=-1}^{1}x\sqrt{1-x^{2}} - 6\pi;
$$
but 
$$
\int_{x=-1}^{1}x\sqrt{1-x^{2}} = \int_{x=-1}^{0}x\sqrt{1-x^{2}} + \int_{x=0}^{1}x\sqrt{1-x^{2}} = 0;
$$
then we are done.

Comment: Good answer! +$1$

Comment: Awesome! I didn't see that last step.

Answer (score 2):

By linearity

$$\int_{-2}^{2} (x-3) \sqrt{4-x^2}dx = \int_{-2}^{2} x \sqrt{4-x^2}dx - 3 \int_{-2}^{2} \sqrt{4-x^2}dx$$

But $\int_{-b}^b f(x) dx = 0$ for odd $f(x)$ (Optional Exercise 25), and $f(x) = x \sqrt{4-x^2}$ is odd.

\begin{align}
\int_{-2}^{2} (x-3) \sqrt{4-x^2}dx &= - 3 \int_{-2}^{2} \sqrt{4-x^2}dx\\
&= -6 \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{4-(2x)^2}dx \qquad \mbox{Contraction, k = 1/2,  Thm 1.19}\\
&= -12 \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}dx \qquad \mbox{Homogeneous property Thm 1.3}\\
&= -6 \pi
\end{align}

Comment: This is also an excellent answer. Thanks!